# The iOS navigation Bar seems not suitable as I set

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

This is a custom Navigation bar,the height I set for it is 64,but it is more than 64 as you can see.I don't how it is happened.

Here is my code:

```
navigationView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 64)];
navigationView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
navigationView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
navigationView.alpha=0.85;
[self.view insertSubview:navigationView atIndex:9999];
```

what confused me most is that it's shown OK on my iPhone5(ios8)  but shown wrong on my iPhone 6(ios9)

Comment: I don't think it is more than 64, if so, then 20 must be the height of status bar.

Comment: yeah,the navigationView has contained the status bar

Comment: instead of 64 put 44 and run let me know once if it is fit correctly

Comment: the 64 = statusBar's 20 + navigationBar'44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this problem by myself.The solution is:New a launch screen of the project.That's the way.Then the status bar would recover to it's correct face.